# add value to new table in mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I have a database on flask mysql and user can login to `profile` page. I need to add description text, but it does not insert into database. What can be the problem?

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        texts = request.form['text']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor() 
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(texts) VALUES (%s)', (texts))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return render_template('profile.html', texts=texts)

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

`profile.html`

```
your id is: {{ id }}
your email is: {{ email }}
your text is: {{ texts }}

<form action="" method="post"> 
<input type="text" class="searchTerm" name="text" placeholder="Add your symptoms">
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="searchButton" name=form>
     <span class="submit-symp">Submit</span>
 </button>
</form>
```

`id` and `email` appear but I can not add data to new column and get it back from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python requires a tuple with two elements, even when one is empty

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(texts) VALUES (%s)', (texts,))
```

O would test the sql command in mysql workbench and test it, depending on the table designb that could fail

IO think you wnat tgo update

```
cur.execute('UPDATE users.data  SET texts = %s WHERE id = ?', (texts,session['id']))
```

Comment: have you tested the query direct in mysql?

Comment: yes. and got this error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: could you give me an example of tests? the query runs in  mysql 8 with out a hickup

Comment: could you please clarify. what examples?

Comment: Check thsi example and modify it to your table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/11

Comment: please check this [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/13) I created SQL statement of my database from myqsl workbench

Comment: as is supsected your query is wrong https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/14  you have to dd values to all columns that have no DEFAULT. so please modify the INSERT till it fits and then use that as blueprint for your python code, with al,lot more %s

Comment: actually I changed INSERT many times, but still unsuccessfully

Comment: the deal is that I need to add more that one description to every user. Maybe I need to create another table and somehow connect it with `users` db?

Comment: Look here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/15 , btw my answer is correct to your question.

Comment: I cant use these forms, on `profile` page, because I have them on `register` page

Comment: your complete code doesnmake sens, what do you try to accomplsh with your query, it can not be to insert a new user. so maybe you want tp update the row?

Comment: I do not want to add new user, I just want to add value from my form to new column in db

Comment: So why do you have it in the frist oalce, see my changed answer and try tthix

Comment: because with your sample it does not work. I tried many times

Comment: i am confused, the insert as stated works. Fact. The Isnert clause is not what you wanted ´, ia dded an update query that should also work.

Comment: but in case it does not affect to the database. such Strange

Comment: could you please clarify why my question was lowered?

Comment: you asked a question you gpt an answer, you clarified, I made an insert in debfiddle that works, i added an update that works too but you didn't act on the comments

Comment: this did not work for me. In my case nothing happens and column of db is still empty

Comment: I noted your answer as right for adding data to database, but could you please check another question and help with it? [another qusetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357245/cant-get-form-name-from-html-to-python)