# can`t get form name from html to python

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, flask

I want to add `description text` from users profile page `to description column` in my database, but when I submit form nothing happens and this column still empty.

I can get `id` and `email` on profile page after login, but can not get `description form` to my `profile method`

This is my database structure [image]

`login method:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']


        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s', 
                    (email, password))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account[0]
            session['email'] = account[3]
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))
        else:
            return render_template('error.html')

    return render_template('login.html')
```

`profile method:`

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        description = request.form['text']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('UPDATE users.data  SET description = %s WHERE id = ?', (description, session['id']))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'], description=description)
    else:
        return 'NO'

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

`profile.html:`

```
your session id is: {{ id }}
your session email is: {{ email }}
your session symptom is: {{ description }}

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" placeholder="description">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Please assist.

Comment: I think you might want `cur.execute('UPDATE users.data  SET description = %s WHERE id = %s', (description, session['id']))` note `%s`, not `?`

Comment: @Nick, unfortunately, this did not help

Comment: Are you sure this line `description = request.form['text']` is getting data correctly?

Comment: @FooL, I have checked it using `print(description)` in console and nothing happens. So, getting data is not correct, but what is the problem? Why do I cant get it?

Comment: @abby try changing the `button` to `<input type="submit"` instead?

Comment: @FooL the deal is that I can not get `description form` to my python and can`t print it in console. It means that nothing sends to database. I still can not fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'loggedin' in session:
            return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'])

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        description = request.form['description']
        print(description)
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
#       cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(description) VALUES (%s)', (description))       
        cur.execute('UPDATE users.data SET description = %s WHERE id = %s', (description, session['id']))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        print(description)
        return render_template('profile.html', description=description)
    else:
        return 'NO'

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```